# Redirect and open popup in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, material-ui

I would like to redirect when submitting a form, and open a popup after being redirected.
I can be redirected but not to open the popup right after. Does anyone know how to do that?

**Hooks state (popup and redirection):**

```
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
const [redirection, setRedirection]= React.useState(false);
```

**functions that open and close popup:**

```
const handleOpenPopUp = () => {
    setOpen(true);
};

const handleClosePopUp = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === 'clickaway') {
      return;
    }
    setOpen(false);
};
```

**Function that submit form, redirect and should open the popup:**

```
const submitForm = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (self.checkValidFormHandler().length > 0) return;
    Api.post('centrale_achat_fournisseur_creer', self.getDataFormHandler(), function (response) {
            if (self.checkValidApiFormHandler(response).length > 0) return ;
            console.log('Success enregistrement');
                handleRedirection(); 
                handleOpenPopUp()
        }
    );
};
```

**The condition that redirect or display the form:**

```
if(redirection)
    return <Redirect to="/centrale-achat/fournisseur/lister"/>
else
    return (        
        <form onSubmit={submitForm} noValidate autoComplete="off">
          <CustomizedSnackbars
            open={open}
            message="lololol"
            variant="success"
            onClose={handleClosePopUp}
          />
         </form>
```

I can open the popup or make the redirection but not both..

Comment: On the component being rendered on /lister, do you have props? can you pass a prop saying that the popup should open?

Comment: try using useEffect/componentDidMount which renders Popup in new component with setTimeOut

Comment: exactly, if you need it to be only when coming from said form, then add a prop

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, I'll try it like this.